# Archival solution for BigQuery tables in a Datawarehouse

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a usecase for building a DataWarehouse using BigQuery, say if a monthly backup needs to be taken for all the BigQuery tables. What would be the best option?

- Export all the table data to Cloud storage (csv?)
- Copy all the tables to a different dataset (and in a different project may be)

What would be the best option, considering the cost and maintenance? And also please share if any other options.

Comment: There are pricing calculators if that is your concern: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/ If you store tables in cloud storage make use of the avro format

Answer (score 0):

When moving data from BigQuery to GCS, you are not charged for the export and load operation, as mentioned in the [Free operation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free) documentation; however, you [incur on charges for storing data in GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) that will depend on the type of the storage selected. This service offers the **Multi-Regional**, **Regional**, **Nearline** and **Coldline** options that you can choose based on the frequency that you need to access to the stored data.

Based on this, in case you want to make your back-ups and don't access the data in a frequent basis, you can store your data in GCS with a **Coldline**/**Nearline** storage or use the [Long-term storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage) in BigQuery, that is automatically applied when table is not edited for 90 consecutive days, and that would be some cheaper options. On the other hand, if you plan to use your data actively, it may be better to use BigQuery with [Active Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#active_storage) which will cost you similar than if you store it in GCS with a Regional storage; nevertheless, it will depend on your specific use-cases and the way you want to interact with your data.

Regarding the ingestion file format, BigQuery support a variety of formats that you can use to load your data. I suggest you to check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#choosing_a_data_ingestion_format) that can help you to decide the format that best fit to your current scenario based on your data structure.